# Spring Cloud Config Server + RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I created spring cloud config server and client and they work as expected. I have added @RefreshScope to my client and I am able to see the new properties getting fetched after hitting /refresh endpoint. But I was told that when I deploy it in cloud foundry environment , I must integrate it with RabbitMQ in order for all the instances to receive the refresh message. Is it possible to point me to a link which explains this problem and solution in detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Spring Cloud Bus](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-bus/)

This is what you need in order to propagate configuration changes to all of your servers via a message broker such as RabbitMQ.

1. **[GitHub Project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus)**
2. **[Documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_bus)**

Follow the instructions in the links above you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume your application runs as single instance configuration. In that case, you don't need spring cloud bus based refresh and just hitting the {app}/actuator/refresh would be enough. Only if you scale out your app, we would need such setup with a queue like RabbitMQ or kakfa.