# Spring Config server add property at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I want to add some property at runtime in spring config server and it should be available to all client applications with `@Value` annotation.

I wont have this property predefine because I am going calculate that value in spring config server and add to environment.

Can you please help me understand what is best way to achieve this.

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873433/spring-cloud-config-server-rabbitmq/37873783#37873783

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Cloud Config Server + RabbitMQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873433/spring-cloud-config-server-rabbitmq)

Comment: Nope its different question

Answer (score 3):

Spring cloud configuration contains a feature named '[RefreshScope](https://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope)' which allows to refresh properties and beans of a running application.

If you read about spring cloud config, it looks like it can only load properties from a git repository, but that is not true.

You can use RefreshScope to reload properties from a local file without any need to connect to an external git repository or HTTP requests.

Create a file `bootstrap.properties` with this content:

```
# false: spring cloud config will not try to connect to a git repository
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
# let the location point to the file with the reloadable properties
reloadable-properties.location=file:/config/defaults/reloadable.properties
```

Create a file `reloadable.properties` at the location you defined above.
You can leave it empty, or add some properties. In this file you can later, at runtime, change or add properties.

Add a dependency to

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

All beans, that are using properties, that may be changed during runtime, should be annotated with `@RefreshScope` like this:

```
@Bean
@RefreshScope
Controller controller() {
    return new Controller();
}
```

Create a class

```
public class ReloadablePropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator
{
       private final String location;

       public ReloadablePropertySourceLocator(
           @Value("${reloadable-properties.location}") String location) {
           this.location = location;
        }

    /**
     * must create a new instance of the property source on every call
     */
    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate(Environment environment) {
        try {
            return new ResourcePropertySource(location);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Configure Spring to [bootstrap the configuration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#_customizing_the_bootstrap_configuration) using that class.

Create (or extend) the `META-INF/spring.factories` file in your resource folder:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=your.package.ReloadablePropertySourceLocator
```

This bean will read the properties from the `reloadable.properties`. Spring Cloud Config will reload it from disk, when you refresh the application.

Add runtime, edit `reloadable.properties` as you like, then refresh the spring context.
You can do that by sending a POST request to the `/refresh` endpoint, or in Java by using `ContextRefresher`:

```
@Autowired
ContextRefresher contextRefresher;
...
contextRefresher.refresh();
```

This should also work, if you choose to use it in parallel to properties from a remote git repository.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for your response. I understand you are suggesting that we can add runtime property in to externalised file and spring config server will automatically load it. But is it possible that I can achieve without writng to file.
Is there a way we do something like environment.addPorperty(key, Value) and it is availabe to all config clients.

Comment: Can it done globally for the project instead of defining beans with @RefreshScope